# How to use Indicator Constraint in Java using Cplex api?

Tags: java, cplex

I am building a model using Java and Cplex, in my model i need to insert a indicator constraint. There are nodes in the model that are denoted by i,j from a set of Nodes 'N' . My Binary decision variable is X[ ][ ] and another continuous variable is Q[ ]. I need to add a constraint such that:
model.add( Q[ j ] >= Q[ i ] - d[ j ] if X[ i ][ j ]==1). 
Here d[ j ] is a constant for Node 'j'. I am looking of an example to do this using Java API and Cplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an indicator constraint using [ifThen](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplexModeler.html#ifThen(ilog.concert.IloConstraint,%20ilog.concert.IloConstraint,%20java.lang.String)). For example (this line of code is untested, but you should get the idea):

```
cplex.add(cplex.ifThen(cplex.eq(X[i][j], 1.0), cplex.ge(Q[j], Q[i] - d[j])));
```

See the `FixNet.java`, `FoodManufact.java`, and `Diet.java` examples that are included when you install CPLEX for more.

Comment: I'm using Java API of CPLEX 12.6.1, and your solution seems correct to me too.
But, after having observed the generated LP file, I noticed that the generated `indicator constraints` use the double-arrow symbol `<->` instead of the right-arrow symbol `->`. Do you know which could be the problem?